# Ordering result with punctuation and symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table like

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

When doing a select on the table the ordering on the username is a bit strange.
Assuming we have the values for the user `test_test` and `test.test`.
What I expect and ordering in, for example using C# and LINQ, results in the ordering of
`test_test` and then `test.test`. The result which I receive by running a query
like `SELECT [Username] FROM [dbo].[Test] ORDER BY Username;` the query returns a ordering
of `test.test` and then `test_test`.

The SQL Server  has a default collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and the
`@@Version` returns `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU12) (KB5004524) - 15.0.4153.1 (X64)`

What is the correct collation or approach to receive the ordering which I expect?

I have currently tried adding different collations to the column especially the collations
which are returned by

```sql
SELECT name, description FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE name like '%Latin1%CI%AI%';
```

Trying the table and queries using a database like PostgreSQL or MySQL returns the correct ordering without changing any collations.

Answer (score 0):

I seems like every collation is putting . first and _ second.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #output
CREATE TABLE #output ( ThisOrder INT, Value NVARCHAR(10), Collation sysname)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @collation sysname

DECLARE collationCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name AS Collation FROM sys.fn_helpcollations();
OPEN collationCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM collationCursor INTO @collation

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @sql = '
        ;WITH b AS (
        SELECT N''test_test'' COLLATE ' + @collation + ' AS Value
        UNION SELECT N''test.test'' COLLATE ' + @collation + ' AS Value)
        INSERT INTO #output
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.Value) AS ThisOrder, b.Value, ''' + @collation + ''' AS Collation
        FROM b'

    EXEC (@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM collationCursor INTO @collation

END
CLOSE collationCursor
DEALLOCATE collationCursor

SELECT * FROM #output AS o
```